# center cells when Adding row to datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm following this [tutorial](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) to add a row to a datatable programatically. And it works fine.

Now, this only permits you to add content to , but several columns in my table needs to be centered.

this is my code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#addTournamentUser", function () {

        var t = $('#table' + categoryTournamentId).DataTable();
        var row = t.row.add([
            "1", // <-- this column must be centered
            "2"),   <-- this column must be left-aligned
        ]).draw(false);
    });
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply classes to certain columns to make them look as you want. For example:

```
var t = $('#table' + categoryTournamentId).DataTable({
   columnDefs: [
      {
         targets: 1,
         className: 'dt-body-center'
      }
   ]
});
```

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wn12thL/) for code and demonstration.